# Different versions of IOS app

Tags: ios, version

I have an app which is base in sqlite DBs and I need to create different versions of it. Each version is using different dbs, the name of them and the url to update them, and some other parameters but the code is develop to be the same in any version.

My question is how to do that keeping it simply. On android I have done several projects as library and I create a new project for each version. the new project is only a class extending from application in which I set the parameters for the name of the dbs and other strings which are defining the url etc. However in IOS I am not sure how to do that and having only one source to update for all versions.

I was reading a bit about targets but I am not sure if this is the best way, even I am not sure how to do it.

What do you recommend me? using targets? how to setup them to change the properties in the original project like the name of the database? Or do you have a better way to do that?

Every thing in the app to change the HMI or the content is in the DBs this is why I use different DBs for each version. Even I use the same DBs for the android versions.

Thanks for your help.

PS: just to clarify a bit more, the two versions has the same functions, it is just the content what is changed, and this content is in the DBs. I am not trying to have a pro and a lite version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the different targets option is perfectly valid in this case, since you can decide which files go into which application. I have a similar app that shares most of the code but there are some specific resources that are specific for each application.

Just be sure that when you add new files to the project the correct target is selected, or if it's a shared resource, then all the targets are selected. You can do so in the utilities panel in XCode.

Comment: Thanks, all the parameters I am using are in info.plist, so I think I have to add one info.plist for each target, isn't it?

Comment: If you already have a target you can right click on it and select **Duplicate** from the menu. It creates another info.plist file that corresponds to the other taget. You have to do a little Renaming in the build settings but it's not that hard.

Comment: Thanks, that's working very well to me. The only thing I have seen is when adding a new class is only added in the first target. I have to add manually in the other because I got an error. Is there a way to add new classes in all targets? or to update the targets automatically?

Comment: When you add a new class, you should see in the dialog the targets with a checkbox. you have to click them both. I'm sure you can do this automatically, but I haven't found out how (it's a bit annoying). The same goes for the resources. If you already added a class you can add them to the other target using the utilities panel (in the top right corner)